# Kinematic Body 2D not moving

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm trying to game a game using the Godot Engine but I'm stuck at the beginning! I can't make my KinematicBody2D move!

This is my Player.GD script

```
extends KinematicBody2D

var velocity = Vector2.ZERO
var move_speed = 480
var gravity = 1200
var jump_force = -720
var right = Input.is_action_pressed("move_right")
var left = Input.is_action_pressed("move_left")
var jump = Input.is_action_pressed("jump")


func _ready():
    pass
    
func _physics_process(_delta):
    var move_direction = int(right) - int(left)
    velocity.x = move_speed * move_direction
    move_and_collide(velocity)
```

Can someone, please, help me?

Answer (score 1):

All this code will run when the `KinematicBody2D` is initialized:

```
var velocity = Vector2.ZERO
var move_speed = 480
var gravity = 1200
var jump_force = -720
var right = Input.is_action_pressed("move_right")
var left = Input.is_action_pressed("move_left")
var jump = Input.is_action_pressed("jump")
```

In consequence, it will not be taking input in real time. Instead you want the last three lines here:

```
func _physics_process(_delta):
    var right = Input.is_action_pressed("move_right")
    var left = Input.is_action_pressed("move_left")
    var jump = Input.is_action_pressed("jump")
    # …
```

---

Those are boolean, by the way. You can get a `float` from `0.0` to `1.0` if you use `Input.get_action_strength` instead. Which will also let your code ready for analog input.

---

I also want to point out that `move_and_collide` does not take a velocity, but a displacement vector. So to call it correctly, you want to multiply the velocity by delta:

```
func _physics_process(delta):
    # …
    move_and_collide(velocity * delta)
```

Or use `move_and_slide`, which does take a velocity. *By the way, the `up` parameter that `move_and_slide` takes is to discern between floor, ceiling, and walls. Without, everything is considered a wall.*